# Where to set the Template Summary property in InstallShield 2015 ISM project?

Tags: templates, installshield, summary

I am using InstallShield 2015. When I open the Install Script project (ISM file) I do not see where I can set Template Summary property under General Information or any other tab. (I want to make it a 64 bit-only installer.)

I can set it under General Information tab when I open the MSI file but the MSI file gets overwritten every time I build the ISM file.

Is it possible to set it in the ISM file?

Answer (score 0):

You're not clear about your edition of InstallShield, but as you mention opening the built .msi file, I'll assume you are using Professional or Premier. In those editions, you can set the architecture portion of the Template Summary property to 64-bit by replacing `Intel` with `x64` in either the Summary Information Stream section of the General Information view, or in a Product Configuration in the Releases view. The latter overrides the former, so if you inherited a project that used the latter, you might think the former is failing.

See [Targeting 64-Bit Operating Systems with Basic MSI and InstallScript MSI Installations](http://helpnet.flexerasoftware.com/installshield22helplib/helplibrary/Targeting64Bit-MSI.htm) in the InstallShield help for this and additional information.

Comment: Yes it is professional edition. My installer produces a EXE not a MSI. In General Information view there is no Summary Information Stream section. In Releases View there is an item "SINGLE_EXE" but even that doesn't have a place to edit Template Summary property.

Comment: That doesn't add up; what are we missing? If you're in a Basic MSI project, or an InstallScript MSI project, the settings should be there. If you're not, you shouldn't get an MSI from your build. Unless it's something like a DISK1 file in a pure InstallScript project; that just copies its source file.